# How to delete unposted journal entries in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo-12

How can i delete an unposted journal entries in Odoo 12 community version.

I have try severally to delete using the delete button but its not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulllz.png)

Comment: Please help with this request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.